# Making a form with checboxes that doesn't overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form element inside a div element to which I am appending checkboxes that correspond to elements in a list. I would like for these checkboxes to not overflow from the div element they are appended to (currently when there are to many checboxes a scroll bar appears and you have to scroll left-to-right to see all the elements).

My function for creating checkboxes:

```
function add_qcm(form_comp){
  console.log("add_qcm lancée")
  const messagesContainer = document.getElementById("chatbox"); //on récupère la fenêtre où les messages doivent apparaitre
  let qcmDiv = document.createElement("div");
  let qcmForm = document.createElement("form")
  let list_comp = form_comp;
  for (let i = 0; i<list_comp.length;i++) {
    var comp = list_comp[i];
    console.log(comp);
    let checkbox = document.createElement("input")
    let leg = document.createElement("label")
    checkbox.type="checkbox";
    checkbox.id= `comp_${i}`;
    checkbox.className = "comp";
    checkbox.value = comp;
    leg.id = "leg_comp";
    leg.htmlFor = `comp_${i}`;
    leg.innerText = comp;
    qcmForm.appendChild(checkbox);
    qcmForm.appendChild(leg);
  }
  qcmDiv.id = "qcm_div";
  qcmDiv.className = "qcm_div";
  qcmForm.id="qcm_form";
  qcmForm.className="qcm_form";
  messagesContainer.appendChild(qcmDiv);
  qcmDiv.appendChild(qcmForm);
  

}
```

The CSS attached:

```
#qcm_div {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  overflow:auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
  word-break: normal;
  
}
#qcm_form {
  
}
#leg_comp {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: please create a runnable snippet.

Comment: I do not know how to do this

Comment: here you have this link on how to do that. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet